# DDNS / NAT / DNS / internal name server

Tags: dns, nat

I have a registered domain and DNS running on a ISP. For this domain, I have NOIP pointing to my home network behind NAT, and it works well, so, from outside, I can type my servername and have it.

I want to be able to have also my internal DHCP and DNS, so i can assign by MAC address and resolve names internally without conflicting with the external DNS and anything else being resolved by OpenDNS or public servers.

Hints, please, are welcome.

Thx in advance.

Comment: What you want to do is common. The [Ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html) is good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo,

I have just implemented a very similar scenario.

Firewall, router and local DNS server functions delivered by pfSense. This is free for personal use, thus easy to experiment. I then bought a Protectli FW4B - a Netgate appliance might be at east as sensible.

The pfSense `Server¦DNS Resolver¦General Settings¦DHCP Registration` allows DHCP registered names to be resolved/accessible from the browser bar.

I used Google Domains initially, and their Dynamic DNS service was easy to set up. Quickly switched to Cloudflare for its automated [DNS-01](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types) Let's Encrypt support which GD lacks. DDNS was even easier. Recommend anticipating the need for HTTPS.

See my [Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013050/how-should-certificates-for-multiple-separate-sub-domain-servers-be-issued-renew) for more.

Comment: not exactly what i'm looking for.  not considering pfSense. anyway, thank you.